# What is this tower I found in Spain?

Tags: spain, identify-this, architecture

42º37'46.6"N, 2º5'12.15"W

No openings on three sides.  Door and windows face south.  No other openings except ditch from underneath, going north to point straight at Azqueta, but it only goes a short distance.  Seems at one time to have had a pipe going from bottom to top.  No signage.

Pipe makes me think of water, but it is on top of a hill, and it is a long way from any point higher or to any village.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel but about history/culture/architecture

Comment: I would suspect a semaphore tower, but having windows on one side only tends to suggest otherwise.  See https://www.google.com/search?q=semaphore+tower&biw=1920&bih=894&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIiaSbza3NAhUBV1IKHVIGD2IQsAQIKA.

Comment: @Relaxed: There are 105 questions with the tag "identify-this."  Are they all "off-topic"?  Should the tag be removed?

Comment: It looks like it's made of concrete, hence not very old. How tall is it and how large are the openings?

Comment: Seems like a watchtower of some sorts, probably from world war II maybe.

Comment: @DumbCoder It wouldn't be a great watchtower if it only has windows in one direction

Comment: I didn't think to take note of the size when I was there.  (Not easy to get to.)  But comparing my memory of the doorway to my own height, I would estimate that the width/depth are both less than three meters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found someone who knows.  One of the residents of Villamayor de Monjardín was three years old when it was built in 1948.  It was a gravity water tower that has since been replaced by pumps.

There is a spring on Montejurra, a mountain some distance away.  They actually ran pipes down into the valley and up this hill to a tank that is no longer in or on the tower.  The base of the tower is the same altitude as Villamayor de Monjardín, so the residents no longer had to carry water in or truck it.  The resident I spoke to owns a vineyard close to Azqueta, so he occasionally had to go up to the tower, which provided his irrigation as well as the running water to Igúzquiza, Azqueta, and [Villamayor de Monjardín](http://www.villamayordemonjardin.es/portal/default.aspx).

He was not sure what year the [Mancomunidad de Montejurra](http://www.montejurra.com/portal/default.aspx) built the current water system that taps into many other springs and rivers to serve a much bigger region.  But that's when the tower stopped being used, and the access roads were reclaimed by local agriculture (which is why it is no longer easy to get to).  The villages of Azqueta and Villamayor de Monjardín are now supplied by a pump somewhere near autovía A-10.

Comment: Nice. I did search for water towers wondering if that would be a possibility, but every one I could find looked much different

Comment: @Berwyn you are probably missing the ironwork that supported the tank, with that concrete tower being the central part where pumps and other machinery were kept.  Ironwork was probably removed at the same time as the tank, as its valuable scrap metal, but the concrete (probably reinforced) tower would have cost money to remove so it was left.

Comment: @Moo You have a keen eye

Comment: @Berwyn Im just used to these structures dotting countrysides - the ironwork may not even have been removed legally, hence why the concrete structure remains - its worthless!

Comment: @Moo Ok. If it comes up on ebay I won't put a bid in for it then!

Comment: There were never any pumps.  It was completely gravity-driven.  It was just a buffer between the spring and the village.  The hill it is on is between the spring on one mountain and the village on another.

Comment: I wonder whether there even was ironwork.  There are no bolt-holes in the walls.

Comment: I wasnt thinking about ironwork bolted to the concrete tower, more 4 separate legs - this is a typical arrangement for water towers.

Comment: Oh, I doubt there were separate legs, since there were no pads in the ground for them.  The tank was probably small.  Since the water source was higher than the village, all they needed the tower for was a buffer for moments of high demand.  The village only has ninety inhabitants today.

Comment: Please keep in mind that in the 1940s postwar Spain steel was scarce - in fact, it was rationed. Furhtermore, Spanish engineering had a strong tradition of concrete structures while other countries leaned more often to steel structures. Therefore, it's not surprising to find a 1948 water tower nearly devoid of ironworks.